# VisualStudio2015 debug issue

Tags: visual-studio

i have a solution

it has 2 projects inside.

there are an exe and a website.

the issue occurred when clicking F5 to start the debug process.

when i have set the exe to the default StartUp project. The exe can run normally, and the break point can be reached correctly.

however, when i have set the website to the defualt StartUp project. The website can be launched, however the breakpoint cannot reach. also the version isn't the latest one, it looks like it is loading the last succeed version (no error and warning too)

I have to right click the website project and click start new instance in the Debug every time I have modified something!(which is very troublesome) [image]

Thus, I want to know why my F5 isn't equal to the Start new instance, as it is working normally in the other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that but the below procedures after struggled from extra many clicks compiling experience.

the cause is that there is unknown reason that the build checkbox isn't checked in the configuration manager. simply check it and everything looks fine again...

hopefully it can save someone time who suffered from this issue in the future

[image]